# Remote Pair Programming in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, pair-programming

Does anyone know of a Visual Studio add-in that allows remote pair programming in Visual Studio?

Something along the lines of [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/), where all users can edit the same document, live, in realtime.

A shared/remote desktop connection where multiple users are in control of the keyboard and mouse is a step in the right direction. However, this solution isn't as good as SubEthaEdit since by default the Visual Studio text editor won't be able to handle simultaneous edits.

Comment: Do you really want programmers to be able to simultaneously edit the same document?  You will be losing the advantage of programmers learning from one another, reviewing each others code, and communicating intent and reasoning as the code is being written.

Answer (score 11):

Personally, having done a fair amount of remote pair programming recently, I prefer [Join.me](https://join.me/). We don't actually both use the keyboard/mouse at the same time, we commit and push changesets using source control and actually swop who is the host.

One of the handful of very popular VNC options would allow both parties to type and have control of the mouse (unlike SharedView, where you have to pass control back and forth), and goes well with Skype voip.

- [UltraVNC](http://www.uvnc.com/)
- [RealVNC](http://www.realvnc.com/)
- [TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)

Comment: This is a good option, but I assume Visual Studio can't handle UltraVNC two users typing at once.

Comment: It should be fine.  The only problem is that you really need to use voip at the same time so between you you know who's typing and who's watching.

Comment: I don't see how passing control is a negative thing - actually quite the opposite.  With an active VOIP or phone call, it is pretty simple to say "Pass me control, please." or "Passing control to you."  I understand the OP said multiple users in control, but I am not sure that he implied that they all be in simultaneous control.  A little too chaotic, in my opinion.

Comment: @joseph you are right, it's just that SharedView is a bit clunky for passing control over, and it gets irritating if you have to do it a lot. Also, if the host knocks their mouse, they immediately get control back and the remote user is stuck.

Comment: Lol @Henrik. You downvoted my answer because on **your** machine, UltraVNC has an exception while installing? :)

Answer (score 10):

[VS Anywhere](http://www.vsanywhere.com) is what you need to do pair programming with Visual Studio

Comment: As of July 2016, www.vsanywhere.com no longer exists

Answer (score 3):

Skype could handle it.  One of the tenets of pair programming is that only one person is at the keyboard and mouse, so all you really need is one-direction screen casting and voice chat.

Comment: True, though even while you have a driver and navigator or whatever, sometimes it's handy for the navigator to be able to point at something on the screen.

Comment: +1 for only one in control at a time

Comment: Pair programming should be one driver-at-a-time for a LITTLE WHILE, and then the drivers should switch. If you're going to switch, skype doesn't do it (unless you're going to check in to source control, pull down on the other side, and share the other screen.).

Comment: @ByronSommardahl I have done it that way using Google Drive (or Dropbox) with a shared folder. That way, users can quickly get current version of code from one another, and some agreement can be made about who is going to commit the changes.

Answer (score 3):

My recommendation is [Team Viewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/index.aspx)

Comment: There may be some new security concerns. Or maybe not. Just a note to not forget reviewing and decide for any tool. They all can change from time to time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use microsoft shared view (although you can't type concurrently, you can point to things with a mouse trail).

And use skype for the conversation part.

Comment: I think that one at a time is actually a plus, and not a negative.  Passing control takes only a moment and the person not in control can point, like you mentioned.  Voice chat/conferencing/phone is also essential for clear communication.  We use SharedView on a regular basis - the price is right and it gets the job done.

Answer (score 0):

We are working on this. You can use beWeeVee.com by now as a workaround. Meanwhile we are working on this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DwXNk-lCIdg

Comment: Also, the extension in the marketplace hasn't been updated since 2010.  https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Corvalius.BeweeveeforVisualStudio

Answer (score 0):

I've just tried a 2,5 h session via Remote Assistance in Windows and that worked pretty good. The most annoying thing was that I couldn't find a way to get it running in fullscreen.

We used Skype for audio and are thinking about running with a webcam as well.

Think I'll try TeamViewer the next time!

Comment: I've used TeamViewer with my cousing but it was too slow for me to be used for more than just short fun.