# Remote Pair Programming for IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, collaboration

Is there a free way to use IntelliJ when pair-programming?

My question is similar to this question which is 10 years old with [Remote Pair Programming in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3186796/remote-pair-programming-in-intellij)
but I was hoping for a more updated answer since many links like screenhero on that question are now broken. I use special libraries that only exist in IntelliJ so using VSC Liveshare is out of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA now [officially supports](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/cwm/code-with-me.html) remote programming by the [Code With Me plug-in](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14896-code-with-me).

See more in [Code With Me Adds Support for JetBrains IDEs v2020.3](https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2020/10/23/code-with-me-jetbrains-ides-v2020-3/) post.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin called [CodeTogether](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14225-codetogether)

Comment: I'll add that [CodeTogether](https://www.codetogether.com) not only works with all IntelliJ-based IDEs, it also works with VS Code, Eclipse, and all IDEs based on those as well.